# jOOQ query that inserts all values but specify one

Tags: java, jooq

Is it possible to write an insert query that uses all values from a record but ones that I specify. The use case is that I want to perform an insert of all fields, but specify the ID from a sequence without having to perform multiple queries or specify each field separately.

Consider the following:

```java
dsl
    .insertInto(TABLE)
    .values(record)
    .execute();
```

That will use all values of `record`. I could specify each field with `set`:

```java
dsl
    .insertInto(TABLE)
    .set(TABLE.ID, SEQUENCE.nextval())
    ... // Other sets.
    .execute();
```

Or create a map of the remaining fields, but there must be a better way. Effectively, I want to write something like the following (invalid):

```java
dsl
    .insertInto(TABLE)
    .values(record)
    .set(TABLE.ID, SEQUENCE.nextval())
    .execute()l
```

I could do it like:

```java
dsl
    .insertInto(TABLE)
    .set(TABLE.ID, SEQUENCE.nextval())
    .set(Arrays.stream(ArrayUtils.removeElement(record.fields(), TABLE.ID))
        .map(field -> Map.entry(field, record.getValue(field)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))
    .execute();
```

I am hoping that there is a better way.

Comment: You could define the database table that it uses the sequence as default value

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right now, we are moving our remaining Hibernate DAOs to jOOQ. We don't want to modify the database at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it with one of your attempts. Write this instead:

```java
dsl.insertInto(TABLE)
   .set(record)
   .set(TABLE.ID, SEQUENCE.nextval())
   .execute();
```

There are also other options:

- You could turn your `TABLE.ID` column into [a client side computed column](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.18/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/)
- You could use the [replacement API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.18/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-replacement/) to auto-transform all your `INSERT` statements to this table and replace any value for the `TABLE.ID` value by `SEQUENCE.nextval()`
- You could use a `DEFAULT` expression on the server, or a trigger

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will use your first option. We use open-source, so option 2 and 3 are not options for us. I totally agree that option 4 is the best. See comments above.

Comment: @Oliver: *"We use open-source, so option 2 and 3 are not options for us."* - Sure, but you might upgrade for other reasons in the future, and then it will be great to remember that there's a generic option, instead of doing this for every statement. Also, others might find this answer too, and may already be licensed...